# Очередь задач в PHP

Tags: очередь, php, yii

По мере создания своего проекта столкнулся с проблемой - есть некоторые действия пользователей, которые могут длиться до нескольких минут. Ясно понятно, что заставлять пользователя ждать, пока выполняются такие длинные запросы к серверу непозволительно! И тут пришел к выводу, что нужно организовать очередь задач, чтобы пользователь нажал ссылку, на сервере сформировалась задача, а пользователю лишь только отображался процесс выполнения задачи.

Даже набросал табличку в БД, но решение получилось не универсальным. Созданная очередь задач умеет выполнять только шелл скрипты, а мне бы хотелось научить ее выполнять еще логику на PHP, и чтобы результаты обоих случаев складывались в БД.

Слышал о RabbitMQ, Apache Message Queue, но мне кажется, что они слишком избыточны для моего случая. Мне нужно-то, делать некоторые проверки на сервере (тут как раз пригодился бы способ выполнения PHP кода, и в зависимости от результата продолжалось бы выполнение задач, или нет), и манипулировать учетными файлами, и просто "тяжелыми" файлами.

Где можно было почитать как организовывать подобные вещи? Может кто сталкивался уже с этим, и нашел решение?

Проект создается на базе фреймворка Yii.

Comment: Так в чем ваша проблема? Вам нужно стандартное решение очереди, почитайте в википедии. Можно сделать на списке, к примеру.

Comment: Послушайте, это очень вкусная задумка у вас ). Я так понял получается что-то вроде сервера внутри сервера и на php? Поправьте меня, если что.

Comment: @istem да, верно, что-то типа виртуального(shared) хостинга.

Comment: В `python` есть `celery` для этого.
А вот как с ним работать из пхп: [PHP client for Celery](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php)

Comment: Делал когда то подобную вещь, в том числе на Yii. В БД создаете таблицу с задачами, вводите поле тип, таким образом можно будет определять shell или php. Тут при проектировании "таск трекера" приходят на помощь шаблоны проектирования. Ну и далее запускаете свой консольный скрипт, скорее всего по крону(зависит от специфики задачи) и в нем получается список задач и выполняете актуальную. Сразу после запуска задачи обязательно надо обновить ее статус(in_progress например), чтобы крон, который запустится позже, не подхватил ее снова. Выполнили, обновили статус или удалили. Ищете новую.

Comment: Попробуйте Gearman.
Вот [здесь](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/tag/gearman) хорошее описание на русском языке.

Comment: Зачем исполнять php в демоне очереди, что мешает запускать php из shell'а?

Answer (score 2):

Воркер на пхп и запускать его по крону. Не?

Comment: Да, возможен и такой велосипед, но Я не могу придумать, как сделать так, чтобы он мог выполнять как shell скрипты, так и php код. Ввести поле "task_type", к примеру?)

Comment: Это уже какая-то псевдоочередь ( Будет теряться время.

Answer (score 0):

> ПО мере создания своего проекта
>   столкнулся с проблемой такого плана -
>   есть некоторые действия пользователей,
>   которые могут длиться до нескольких
>   минут.

Это ужасно! Это следствие плохой структуры БД и скриптов. Что такого может выполняться, да к тому же у каждого пользователя по минуте по две?

Ладно обработка нескольких таблиц с математическими действиями по подсчете скидок у 16К клиентов и 25К заказов. Тут да у меня на серваке до 8 минут считаются, но раз в день и для всех сразу, а не для каждого по отдельности.

> Я даже набросал табличку в БД, и все
>   бы хорошо, но решение получилось не
>   универсальным. Созданная очередь задач
>   умеет выполнять только шелл скрипты, а
>   мне бы хотелось научить ее выполнять
>   еще логику на php, и чтобы результаты
>   обоих случаев складывались в БД.

В Yii есть [консольные приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/128990/yii-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)([и тут](http://demura.su/articles/yii-framework/konsolnye_prilozheniya_v_yii_framework/)), юзай их. Делай там и логику и операции с данными. Не нужно изобретать с данном случае велосипед.

Comment: @Shrek бывает всякое. Один мой знакомый (тогда -- коллега) для таких вот запросов делал специальную "выжимку" из базы (раз в сутки). А пользовательские запросы уже брали информацию из этой выжимки. (Недостаток -- пока "большой" запрос не завершён, информацию пытаться получить бесполезно. Но по тем условиям работы это было приемлемо)

Comment: @Shrek, когда в проекте предполагается работа с архивами большого размера - это плохая структура БД? Увы, у меня нет таких мощностей, как например во вконтакте, или гугла, которые способны "на-лету" делать все)

Подсчет скидок - вещь весьма тривиальная, и Я бы ее реализовал сам, без вопроса здесь)

Comment: @nolka, тогда php вам не подходит, именно но причите однопоточности.
Посмотрите в сторону java.

Comment: @dimka3210, многопоточность здесь не при чем :] Никто не мешает запускать пхп скрипты в несколько потоков :]