# Выполнение задачи в фоне (php)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

**Стоит такая задача:**

```
Есть консольное приложение, которое должно выполняться, если пользователь нажмет на кнопку. Оно выполняется достаточно долго. В то же время пользователь может переходить по разным разделам сайта. Задача при этом останавливаться не должна. Она просто должна выполниться до конца.
```

Вот пример скрипта консольного (файл test.php):

```
<?php
     sleep(120);
?>
```

Когда клиент посылает запрос, мы его обрабатываем:

```
<?php
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    exec("/path/to/file/test.php &");
?>
```

Здесь мы просто выполняем наш тестовый скрипт и все.

Запрос приходит аяксом. Скрипт запускается, все хорошо, отрабатывает. Кнопка снова активируется.

**Проблема:**

```
Если мы нажмем на кнопку, а потом попробуем обновить страницу, то приходится ждать, пока скрипт не отработает.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Почитайте здесь: http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/web-development/6293012 Если не получится, попробуйте добавить посредника - bash скрипт. В котором вы будете вызывать .php c приставкой &. Основной скрипт запросит exec('bash') - в bash-файле запустится фоновый .php - bash скрипт завершится, фоновый процесс останется.

Comment: @istem там обсуждение похожее и как итог ты до конца прочитал ссылку?

1. Ставим в web-скрипте выполнение программы на очередь (очередь делай хоть табличкой в БД, хоть каталогом с файлами).
2. Кроном от правильного пользователя, с правильными привилегиями запускаем внешнюю программу, обрабатывающую элемент очереди и записывающую результат в журнал
3.Читаем web-скриптом состояни очереди и записи в журнале (хоть аяксом, хоть нажимая F5)

4. N) ВЫГОДА!

Comment: вопрос решен

@Shrek, "дело в коде". Дело не в коде. Дело в файлах пользователя. Их у него может быть под 10 гб. И если он захочет выполнить операцию вне очереди, которая и так висит на кроне, то ничего тут не поделаешь. Надо будет выполнять. А потом и кидать в хранилище. И сброс в его хранилище может занять уйму времени. Где тут оптимизировать? Увеличивать скорость обмена с внешним хранилищем пользователя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, с таким подходом — никак. Потому что этот скрипт занимает весь Thread.

Есть вариант запускать `exec("/path/to/file/test.php &");` но не так, а так: `exec("/usr/bin/php /var/www/path/to/file/test.php &");` и не спать, а переложить выполнение на этот второй процесс. А если нужны данные ответа твоего "/path/to/file/test.php", то брать их из sdtout или в самом скрипте "test.php" записать вывод в файл — его наличие как-раз оповестит о том, что скрипт выполнился.

Подробнее [в Q&A на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/1188/).

Comment: @Bars, на самом деле скрипт вызывается через yiic (Yii), а там внутри вызывается php

Comment: Я не знаком с yiic, но что, это мешает запустить /usr/bin/php самостоятельно? yiic — это обертка какая-то? Тогда придется велосипедить, чтож. По-моему, иначе никак. Ну и еще можно выделить отдельную машину со своим отдельным процессом похапе под это консольное приложение. Но опять же — по-идее, сможет отрабатывать только одна копия приложения, так как php-скрипт будет ждать его завершения.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно сделать так:

```
// Игнорируем отмену загрузки страницы пользователем
ignore_user_abort();

// Говорим что время на выполнение скрипта не ограничено
set_time_limit(0);

// Говорим что соединение надо закрыть
header('Connection: close');

// Перенаправляем если нужно
//header('Location: http://site.com');

// Отчищаем все буферы вывода 
@ob_end_flush();
@ob_flush();
@flush();

// Заканчиваем сессию пользователя (именно сессия и не давала 
// запускать выполнение ещё одного скрипта для этого пользователя 
// т.к. запуск скриптов лочится на файл сессий)
if(session_id()){
    session_write_close();
}

// Тут выполняем свой очень долгий скрипт
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1) Юзер нажимает кнопку.
2) Создаеться некий файл в некой директорий с каким то флагом.
3) запускаем CURL - ом некий файл, который игнорируя юзер аборт смотрит файл и выполняеть, соответственно флагу, при завершений пишет свой результат.
4)страница, при обновлений будеть проверять это файл на существования(имя файла можно записать в сессию), и если есть то смотрит флаг.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Есть консольное приложение
```

Они и должны выполняться из консоли, а вот как их запускать в отдельном процессе в помощь [недавний вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197722/yii-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87-%D0%B2-php) там про очередь выполнения все написано.

А то что написано у тебя, работать по твоей логике не будет.

//UPD комменты жгут как обычно. Их нехватает.

Я на самом деле даже дальше и думать не хочу, я предложил хороший вариант решения задачи, он адекватный и по затратам памяти хороший, т.к. скрипты выполняются из консоли, что требует меньше памяти, чем выполнение их через браузер.

Очередь нужна. Попробуй 100 раз запустить свой скрипт, твой сервер ругнется и выполнять ничего не будет. если на выполнение ему нужно 10-15 минут - тут оптимизацией заняться нужно т.к. ответ на вопрос уже есть, а додумывать что-то из ряда вон выходящее без причин безумно глупо.

Пойми, сделав очередь - ты никого не обидешь этим. В фейсбуке многие вещи не обновляются сразу, там бывает проходит от 5 до 15 минут, пока новость/картинка/статья добавится в общую ленту.

Из того что ты написал непонятно из-за чего так долго все выполняется. Значит дело в коде. Если на каждого юзера уходит 10 минут процессорного времени - это жуть! А будет из 100К, этож сколько денег нужно на сервера и память чтобы обрабатывать чстолько непонятно чего.

А так, нажал юзер на кнопку и забыл про её существование, когда дело дойдет до него он получит свой ответ и его данные будут обработаны.

Если ты не можешь выбрать из предложенных вариантов ни одного, тогда тут мало кто тебе чем поможет, можешь пойти изобрести велосипед :). Я дальше, честно не знаю чем тебе помочь. Ты настаиваешь на каком-то своем решении вопроса, не вчитываясь в ответы других.

ps
Notes

```
PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see flush().
```

Comment: почитал-почитал
http://hashcode.ru/questions/197722#197837

1. Задачу не нужно запускать по крону. Ее нужно запустить сразу же, как пользователь нажал на кнопку

2. Если пользователь не разорвет соединение, то мы вернем ему ответ

Comment: ну возьми ajax запрос отправь какому-нить контроллеру, а тот запустит консольное приложение.

Comment: @Shrek, так и сделано. По нажатию на кнопку отправляем запрос ajax-ом. Но пользователю все-равно приходится ждать завершения операции

Comment: Тогда тут по любому Таблицу делать для очереди и по крону проверять. Иначе никак.

Результат будет получен через 5 минут, пользователю ждать не хочется, значит все это нужно переложить на сторону сервера, а кроме как в очередь задач и по крону ты этого не сделаешь.

Вывод один.

Comment: @Shrek, блин. Беда какая-то.

Тут все дело в том, что эта задача может выполниться и за 3 секунды. А это время пользователь наш готов ждать (пока ему там все крутится).

Хорошо, почему тогда по моей логике не будет работать?
Я думал, что если мы игнорим разрыв соединения, то задача выполнится 100%. Ну она и выполняется 100%. Но если пользователь обновляет страничку, то он рвет соединение. Почему тогда ему приходится ждать завершения задачи? которая была запущена в предыдущем соединении?

Comment: >Оно выполняется достаточно долго.

Это твои слова? Или достаточно долго это 3 сек?

>В то же время пользователь может переходить по разным разделам сайта.

Если хочешь сделать так, тогда очередь и cron. 

Соединение будет прерываться если юзер уходит на другую страницу или обновляет её.